# A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined variable: id Filename: models/singlequery_model.php Line Number: 4

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: id

Filename: models/singlequery_model.php

Line Number: 4

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

SELECT * FROM patient WHERE id =

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\login\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Is this the right way to query a single result?

```
    <?php
class Singlequery_model extends CI_Model{
    function get_query(){
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM patient WHERE id  = $id");

        if($query->num_rows() > 0 ){
            foreach ($query->result() as $row){
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my controller

```
    <?php 
class Site extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
      $this->is_logged_in();
      $this->load->model('site_model');

    }
    function delete(){
      $this->site_model->delete_row();
      redirect('site/members_area');
    }

    function view(){

        $this->load->model('singlequery_model');

        $data['records'] = $this->singlequery_model->get_query();
        $this->load->view('patient_update', $data);

    }
```

}

Comment: And what problem do you have? You have line `$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM patient WHERE id  = $id");` and Singlequery_model you don't have defined `$id`

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM patient WHERE id  = $id");
```

`$id` is not defined in your class

for this, make sure you call the function with `$id`:

```
$data['records'] = $this->singlequery_model->get_query($id);
```

I have no way of knowing where your `$id` comes from, so you're on your own to manage that.

Comment: I was asking what's the correct way to query because I got that error even I put function get_query($id){
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM patient WHERE id  = $id");

        if($query->num_rows() > 0 ){
            foreach ($query->result() as $row){
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
}

Comment: @JohnDanielVogue please update your question with your new not-working code, I'll update my answer accordingly. But it is not enough to only put `function get_query($id)` you must add it to the function *call* as well